# What are all the programs to uninstall to remove visual studion 2008 express?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, uninstallation, addremoveprograms

I am a novice tool user but was required to load VS 2008 for a class I was taking which we only used one time.  I did not register the copy on my one time use and now 6 months later am required to use VS 2005 for another class.  My problem - I need to uninstall 2008 and install 2005.  I'm not sure what programs to uninstall from the  Add/remove programs list. I need specific names and order so I can do it right and not mess up.

I know many would say why not just use 2008 - well I do have 2008 on a laptop I also have but it does not seem to have some of the templates that the instructor has on 2005 like "windows application template".  Am I missing something in my 2008 or is it some other name or location that I don't understand.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks, 
Robin

Answer (score 1):

You really don't need to uninstall anything. Just go ahead and install Visual Studio 2005. They work side by side without any problems. Heck, I have 4 versions of Visual Studio on my workstation.

If you must, you'll need to remove:

- Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 ...
- Microsoft Document Explorer 2008
- MSDN Library for Visual Studio 2008 [if you had it installed]
- Microsoft SQL Server (Express) [if you had it installed]

Answer (score 0):

You could try re-installing the templates as described [here](https://www.johncmurphy.com/category.aspx?cid=91).

And for removing the programes, have a look at this page:

http://www.microsoft.com/express/support/uninstall/default.aspx

It applies to pre-release versions, but it has the list of programs and the order which you should remove them.

I hope this helps.